# Python Camelot - export one PDF file to one converted file

Tags: python, python-camelot

Python 3.7 with Camelot 0.7.3.

By default, Camelot exports separate converted files for each page of the pdf file.  I need it so that one pdf file exports to one converted file (HTML conversion is what we use), regardless of how many pages the pdf file is.  The documentation does not cover this scenario.  Is there a way to achieve this without using `compress=true`?  A zip file will not work in our application.

Comment: This is not so straight.
You can try to export the tables to various HTML and then merge them using python.

Comment: A suggestion. You opened 2 or 3 very similar questions. If the problem is the same, please consider explain it better and close the duplicate questions.